# Growing a list inside a for loop returns NAs

Tags: r, loops

I would like to take back some indexes using a for loop and right now, the loop returns only NAs.

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                 v2 = c("f", "g", "h", "i", "j"),
                 v3 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "dd"))

vec <- c("aa", "bb", "ee")

res <- list()


for (i in(vec)){
 temp <- vec[i]
 res[[i]] <- grep(temp, df[,3])
}
```

gives

```
res

$aa
[1] NA NA NA NA NA

$bb
[1] NA NA NA NA NA

$ee
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

while I am struggling for this

```
res

$aa
[1] 1

$bb
[1] 2 4

$ee
[1]
```

What is this very simple thing that I keep being unaware of?

Comment: You are looping over the length of vec hence need `seq_along` or `1:length`. Otherwise, you're subsetting with actual values in `vec` not their indices which won't work hence the `NA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `pattern` vector, invoke the `grep` specify the argument 'x' as 'v3' column

```
lapply(vec, grep, x = df$v3)
```

---

Or use anonymous function call

```
lapply(vec, function(pat) grep(pat, df$v3))
```

---

The `list` `res` can be initialized in OP's post as

```
res <- vector('list', length(vec))
```

then loop over the sequence of the 'vec'

```
for (i in seq_along(vec)){
   temp <- vec[i]
   res[[i]] <- grep(temp, df[,3])
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                 v2 = c("f", "g", "h", "i", "j"),
                 v3 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "dd"))

vec <- c("aa", "bb", "ee")

sapply(vec, grep, df$v3)
#> $aa
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $bb
#> [1] 2 4
#> 
#> $ee
#> integer(0)
```